# Wordpress Homepage Overflow and Creating Blank Space

Tags: wordpress

I am using BeTheme. I tried following: Removed Slider and Tried Removing Content but still problem is same. Whereas other page works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css and check

```
@media(max-width:767px){
    body.mobile-side-slide {
       margin: 0px;
       overflow: auto !important;
    }
}
```